# Creating table for database using php script, wont work?

Tags: php

I am trying to create table to my database from php. I kinda trying to make a social networking site, anyway, I wrote the code and is working but new table won't create in database, I don't know what seems to be wrong with the code. Help will be much appreciated thanks!

```
<?php

    $host = "host";   
    $user = "user";
    $pswd = "password";
    $dbnm = "db";

    $conn = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pswd, $dbnm);
    if (!$conn)
        die ("<p>Couldn't connect to the server!<p>");

    $selectData = @mysqli_select_db ($conn, $dbnm);
    if(!$selectData)
    {
        die ("Database Not Selected");
    }

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST 'friends' 
            (
            'friend_id' INT NOT NULL auto_increment, 
            'friend_email' VAR CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
            'password' VAR CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
            'profile_name' VAR CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            'date_started' DATE NOT NULL,
            'num_of_friends' INT unsigned,
            PRIMARY KEY ('friend_id')
            )";

    $query_result = @mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: What is the error message you see?

Comment: Suppressing errors is considered bad practice (The `@` operator). Please don't.

Comment: Run it from a mysql client. You `CREATE TABLE` syntax is wrong.

Comment: Don't do that. Design the structure and create it in a tool like PHPMyAdmin. Only bother with creating tables from code (to be able to easily setup your software on another server) when the software is mostly done and you know how to retrieve and show the errors MySQL gives you.

Comment: I don't see any error, but whenever I go check on the mysql site, I don't see my new table created in the database

Comment: It is `EXISTS` and not `EXIST`. There should not be any space between `VAR` and `CHAR`. Don't wrap your table name and field names within single quotes.

Comment: You won't see any errors if you suppress them with @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for errors when running scripts also, so either turn off suppression (remove the @ symbol) or else check for an error after running.

There were in fact multiple errors:

1. You had `EXIST` rather than `EXISTS`
2. You used single quotes ( ' ) rather than the ` mark
3. You had `VAR CHAR` as two words, rather than the correct `VARCHAR` (one word)

   ```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `friends`  
         (  
         `friend_id` INT NOT NULL auto_increment,   
         `friend_email` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
         `password` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
         `profile_name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
         `date_started` DATE NOT NULL,  
         `num_of_friends` INT unsigned,  
         PRIMARY KEY (`friend_id`)  
         )
   ```

Comment: thank you so much, I got blind with the difference between ` and ' and the syntax, thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you are debugging a script, remove the "@" before the functions. They will suppress the warnings which will otherwise quickly guide you to the errors.

Your create table statement has a lot of syntax errors. Try the corrected one -

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` 
        (
        `friend_id` INT NOT NULL auto_increment, 
        `friend_email` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
         `password` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        `profile_name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        `date_started` DATE NOT NULL,
        `num_of_friends` INT unsigned,
        PRIMARY KEY (`friend_id`)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in CREATE TABLE. You should have written `CREATE TABLE tablename IF NOT EXISTS` (EXISTS should end in S). I also suggest you not suppressing errors and also print errors after every query like this:

```
if(!mysqli_query($conn, $sql) { die("The query ".$sql." failed: ".mysqli_eror }
```