# Table not creating PHP mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, create-table

I am trying to create a table using PHP and MySQL. the first table will not create on the data base but the second one will. I think its my parameters/constraints. Here is my code:

```
if ($conn==true){
     $tablefriends = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS friends (
        friend_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
        friend_email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
        password VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL ,
        profile_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
        date_started DATE NOT NULL ,
        num_of_friends INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NULL default '0'
        );";

    $tablemyfriends = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myfirends ( 
        friend_id1 INT NOT NULL , 
        friend_id2 INT NOT NULL 
        );";

    $resulttf = @mysqli_query($conn, $tablefriends);
    if($resulttf==false){
        echo "<p>Failed to create friends table</p>";
        }
    $resulttmf = @mysqli_query($conn, $tablemyfriends);
    if($resulttmf==false){
        echo "<p>Failed to create myfriends table</p>"; 
        }else{

    echo"<p>Tables successfully created</p>";
        }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}

else {
    echo "<p>Failed to connect</p>";
    }
```

---

I don't know why the tutor has said to put in the primary in twice

Comment: Follow the suggestions regarding suppressing errors given to you in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100937/creating-table-for-database-using-php-script-wont-work.

Comment: multiple primary keys are used in first table, running it through a mysql gui tool or phpmyadmin would have helped you to debug yourself.

Comment: Once the primary keys are fixed, the next question will be about performance, as there's no indexes defined for myfriends

Answer (score 5):

2 **[Primary keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html)**. **`friend_id`** and **`friend_email`**

Always check your query out, before putting it into **PHP**.

Comment: really?

my assignment sheet asks for them to both have primary key

> friend_id – the unique numeric identifier, e.g., 1023. Set this field’s properties as ‘integer, ‘not null’, ‘auto_increment’ and ‘primary key’.
· friend_email – the unique email identifier used for logging in to the system, e.g., user@gmail.com. Set this field’s properties as ‘varchar, ‘size=50’, ‘not null’, and ‘primary key’.

Comment: You can't have 2 primary keys. You could have a [**composite primary key**](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx) for 2 columns. Or else, `unique-key` for the second field.

Answer (score 1):

In Your first query(`$tablefriends`) you had  defined two primary keys. Hope below code  will work for you.

```
 if ($conn==true){
         $tablefriends = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS friends (
            friend_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
            friend_email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL ,
            password VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL ,
            profile_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
            date_started DATE NOT NULL ,
            num_of_friends INT (64) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NULL default '0'
            );";

        $tablemyfriends = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myfirends ( 
            friend_id1 INT NOT NULL , 
            friend_id2 INT NOT NULL 
            );";

        $resulttf = @mysqli_query($conn, $tablefriends);
        if($resulttf==false){
            echo "<p>Failed to create friends table</p>";
            }
        $resulttmf = @mysqli_query($conn, $tablemyfriends);
        if($resulttmf==false){
            echo "<p>Failed to create myfriends table</p>"; 
            }else{

        echo"<p>Tables successfully created</p>";
            }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }

    else {
        echo "<p>Failed to connect</p>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the GRANTS given to the user running the query? Maybe the user can only create the second table.

Have a look in the MySQL log file and see if there are any error messages that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($conn==true){
     $tablefriends = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS friends (
        friend_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
        friend_email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
        password VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL ,
        profile_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
        date_started DATE NOT NULL ,
        num_of_friends INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NULL default '0'
        );";

    $tablemyfriends = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myfirends ( 
        friend_id1 INT NOT NULL , 
        friend_id2 INT NOT NULL 
        );";

    $resulttf = @mysqli_query($conn, $tablefriends);
    if($resulttf==false){
        echo "<p>Failed to create friends table</p>";
        }
    $resulttmf = @mysqli_query($conn, $tablemyfriends);
    if($resulttmf==false){
        echo "<p>Failed to create myfriends table</p>"; 
        }else{

    echo"<p>Tables successfully created</p>";
        }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}

else {
    echo "<p>Failed to connect</p>";
    }
```